# Chat Room Box on right disappears sometimes

Tags: discussion

OK - I deleted my question earlier but I noticed when I came back to the page that the box advertising the chat room wasn't showing again on the main page.

Is there an issue with it or can it be pinned to more consistently appear? I wonder if it is to do with why the chat room is so quiet.

Comment: It is very quiet...I guess no one wants to talk. I was told to ask a question in there...and a week and a half later nothing.

Answer (score 1):

What shows up on the side appears to be something that is related to a per-site configuration.  FAQ & Featured, Chat, Advertisements - these each appear to have a set % display (most per-site metas appear to have FAQ & Featured at 0).

The specifics of what it is and discussion of what it *should* be are something that can be asked (this post may get sufficient SE attention) and configured.

Note also that the [questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) link shows tags on the sidebar, while the [front page](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com) shows chat.

Related: MSE [FAQ sidebar for per site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240284/213963)

Answer (score 0):

I only ever see it on the meta site when I just browse to it. Basically, it disappears if you click any of the links (e.g. questions, ask, etc...), so to see it again just click the site title itself which shows active questions by default.

However, if you click the little down arrow beside "StackExchange" in the title bar, you'll get a link into chat and the blog (the blog is really kind of defunct, but we have one in any event). That's generally the path I take and I have a few chat rooms I've marked as favourites to make them easy to get to.

Comment: That's not exactly making it easy to get new 'footfall' though is it? :)

Comment: @JamWheel - In the immortal words of Lynn Anderson, _I never promised you a rose garden..._ ;) Actually, I'm surprised it's that obscure too but since I'm regularly connected to it, I don't think about it much anymore.